# Session variable does not update in my script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am toying with javascript and I came across a weird issue here. I use Ruby on Rails on the server side.

Here is the HTML part that I want to be dynamics:

```
<div id="pic">
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<%=@id.to_s%>/picture?type=large">
</div>
```

Here is the code called when the event `onreadystatechange` of my AJAX request is raised:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  alert(<%=@id.to_s%>);
  document.getElementById("pic").innerHTML = "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/<%=@id.to_s%>/picture?type=large\">";
}
```

Basically, my request is handled server side where the value of the variable `@id` is changed (it works fine, as seen using the debugguer). Therefore when the javascript code is interpreted, the variable's value also should have changed on the client side according to my expectations... But it did not, which is my issue.

My guess here is that this bit of code `<%=@id.to_s%>` is evaluated once the script is loaded in the browser, not each time the function is called.

Is there a workaround for that?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess here is that this bit of code <%=@id.to_s%> is evaluated once the script is loaded in the browser, not each time the function is called.

Exactly. If that weren't the case, you wouldn't even need ajax to accomplish that.

> Is there a workaround for that?

The proper way to do that is to pass whatever data you need from the server-side, then access it on your js from `onreadystatechange` event handler (which you already seem to be using). The server response will be available as a string at `xmlhttp.responseText`.